# Does syriac language support in iText 7?

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I'm using iText7 with pdfHTML(Version 2.0.0) to create the PDF. I want to print Syriac text(RTL language) in the pdf. Used below code in the HTML file.

```
<p style="font-family:'Estrangelo Edessa'" align="right">ܣܘܪܝܝܐ</p>
```

Added pdfCaligraph(version 2.0.0) as reference to the project. I followed same way to print Arabic font. That is shown in pdf in right to left.
But Syriac text displayed as Left to Right. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

## Disclaimer: I am an employee at iText Software

Syriac is not supported as of the most recent release of pdfCalligraph, nor will it be supported in the upcoming release which is due in a few weeks. The company has prioritized support for "complex scripts", meaning mostly Semitic and Indic writing systems, based on requests from users and customers. You are the very first user (that I know of) to request support for Syriac, so you can consider this the start of the evaluation process on whether we will support it.

I cannot guarantee that Syriac will be supported, but it looks like the writing system is structurally similar to Arabic which is already supported, which makes it likely that we can easily support it.